# Docker does not seem to recognize my daemon.json file

Tags: docker, docker-daemon

As the C drive of my pc is rather small, I wanted to save images to my D drive. For this purpose, I created a `daemon.json` file at `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json`. Inside, I only put the following:

```
{
"data-root": "d:\\docker"
}
```

However, when building a new image, it does not seem to end up in the specified folder... Any ideas?

Edit: I had to create the config folder as well as the `daemon.json` file myself, though I believe this is intended.

Comment: did you restart Docker for desktop app?

Comment: Yes, numerous times.. No effect though